# unable to add custom field to sales order grid in magento ce 1.9.2

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

i have modified `_prepareCollection` method and added left join like this -

```
$collection->getSelect()->join(
    'sales_flat_order', 
    'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id', 
    array('tax_order_type')
);
```

added the column in `_prepareColumns` -

```
$this->addColumn('tax_order_type', array(
    'header' => 'Tax Order Type',
    'type'  => 'text',
    'index' => 'tax_order_type',
));
```

`$collection->printLogQuery(true);` in `_prepareCollection` gives me correct query and i can get the data required using that query as well. But it wont show in grid.

Answer (score -1):

//Compare your code with below link blog.

http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/adding-customer-group-column-to-sales-grid-in-magento/